# Convert array of objects into object

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my object:

```
initialState:any = [{'checked':true}, {'checked':false}, {'checked':true}, {'checked':false}, {'checked':true}, {'checked':false}];
```

This is the output that I expect:

```
var params = {
    "device0":"true",
    "device1":"true",
    "device2":"false",
    "device3":"true",
    "device4":"false",
    "device5":"true",
    "device6":"false",
    "device7":"true"
}
```

I have an array of objects. I want to take value from an object and want to build single object as mentioned above.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 1):

Few records inside the array you provided are different than the result you expect the same as it's length.

```js
var initialState = [{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false}],
    params = {};
    
    initialState.forEach((v,i) => params['device' + i] = v.checked);
    console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var initialState = [{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false}],
   params = initialState.reduce( function( o, item, index ) {
       o["device" + index] = item.checked
       return o;
   }, {})

console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the sinlge objects.

```js
var any = [{ checked: true }, { checked: false }, { checked: true }, { checked: false }, { checked: true }, { checked: false }],
    params = Object.assign({}, ...any.map((a, i) => ({ ['device' + i]: a.checked.toString() })));
    
console.log(params);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```